# Reusability of repeatable code in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have 10 inputs in my webpage, out of which 4 inputs requires date(Date of birth, Purchase date and many), I have my own custom calendar. Currently I'm repeating the code below all 4 inputs which requires date, Is there any efficient way to do without repeating

Comment: Use a function or loop.

Comment: you can try angular custom directive

Comment: Please try to improve your question [codes, images], this is much better.

Comment: @Maher The question is pretty clear...

Answer (score 1):

Since you are already using AngularJS, and already have your own custom calendar, you can change your custom calendar to a directive. Since, there are multiple instances of directive in a single page, create directive have isolated scope, and use this directive in your form.

Similarly, for validation too, you can create your own directive to do validations.

Answer (score 0):

> I have 10 inputs in my webpage, out of which 4 inputs requires date

What you should be doing for a date input is using the [`date` input type](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date).  This gives you a semantically correct form.

> I have my own custom calendar

Write your own polyfill for the date input type, overriding whatever you need.

> Reusability of repeatable code in html

In the general case, consider using Web Components.  https://www.webcomponents.org/  This is a newly revived standard around reusable HTML, and works much the same way a lot of front-end frameworks do.